# best way to convert datetimes in globally synchronised system architecture

Tags: java, datetime

We are working on a Customer Data Integration project (using Java 8), which has a central database that is kept synchronised with local databases in other countries.

When a new or updated contact request comes from a local system to our central system, a modifiedAt value is passed (which is the local datetime stamp value in their time zone)

We convert this into UTC and store it in our database. (To do this we store the time zone offsets for each system). When any system requests that contact object, we convert the stored modifiedAt value from UTC into their local datetime.

Is this the best way to do this? What about issues with daylight savings times? Does the central system need to keep track of when DST starts and stops for each of the local systems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Don't store the timezone **offset**. Store the **timezone** itself.

The offset of "Europe/Paris" is different in the winter and in the summer, due to DST.

But if I know that the timezone is "Europe/Paris", I'm able to reliably convert any French local date to a UTC timestamp, because I can find the right offset *for that local date*.

(actually, I can convert *almost* any date reliably, because some local dates are ambiguous, when the time goes back from 3AM to 2AM).

Why don't the local systems provide a UTC timestamp directly, instead of providing a local datetime?

Comment: The local systems are legacy systems and are difficult to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37898643/1876620): you should store the time zone instead of just the offset. In Java 8, you can use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class to accomplish this.

It contains methods such as:

[`public static ZonedDateTime of(LocalDateTime localDateTime, ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-)

which allow to easily convert a local dateTime to a zoned dateTime. Then, you can move this zoned dateTime to UTC with similar methods, i.e:

[`public ZonedDateTime withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at storing two information [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

In your database, you store the time as Instant. Whenever any of your server asks for the time, you convert that to `ZonedDateTime` using `Instant` value stored in database, and `ZoneId` either passed by server, or stored in database as well.

This allows you to easily query databases in cases you want "All objects that were updated in last hour".

> Instant to ZonedDateTime

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
// Japan = UTC+9
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
```

> ZonedDateTime to Instant

`zonedDateTime.toInstant();`